# How do I prove that $e^{tA}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} ((I-\frac{tA}{n})^{-1})^n$?

Tags: calculus, analysis

> Prove that $$e^{tA}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \left(\left(I-\frac{tA}{n}\right)^{-1}\right)^n.$$

I have no idea how to prove this equation. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

By  [Prove that $\displaystyle\lim_{k \to \infty} (I + \frac{1}{k}A)^{k} = e^{A}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/727067/prove-that-displaystyle-lim-k-to-infty-i-frac1kak-ea) , we have that
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \left(\left(I-\frac{tA}{n}\right)^{-1}\right)^n =
\left(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \left(I+\frac{(-tA)}{n}\right)^n\right)^{-1}=(e^{-tA})^{-1}=e^{tA}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Assume without loss of generality that $t = 1$. The results clearly holds for diagonal and thus diagonalizable $A$, and such matrices are dense in this space of all matrices of given dimensions.