# Limit of a polynomial with matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, analysis

Find $\lim_{m \rightarrow \infty}(1+ \frac{\begin{equation*}
\begin{pmatrix}
 2 & 3 \\
3 & 2
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}}{m})^m$

I know that we can diagonalize the matrix. By diagonalization, we have \begin{equation*}
A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & -1 \\
1 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
 5 & 0 \\
0 & -1 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
 \frac{1}{2} &  \frac{1}{2} \\
 -\frac{1}{2} &  \frac{1}{2} 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
That's what's being usually done when computing the limit of a matrix. I also know that we can use the binomial expansion for $(1+x)^n$. But I'm not sure how to continue from here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you diagonalised the matrix then? What did you get?

Comment: You can also diagonalize  the matrix $I + \frac{1}{m}  A$   and forget about binomials

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( 1 + \frac a n \right)^n = e^a$$

(This is normally stated for real $a$, but the matrix case is elaborated upon [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/727067/prove-that-displaystyle-lim-k-to-infty-left-i-frac1ka-rightk).)

Hence your limit can be found as $\exp(PDP^{-1})$ for your diagonalization.